# how to get `_id` after upserting document in mongo-c-driver or mongo-cxx-driver?

Tags: c++, c, mongodb, mongo-c-driver, mongo-cxx-driver

How to get `_id` after upserting document in mongo-c-driver Or mongo-cxx-driver?

The following code snippet is from mongo-shell, Which shows the `_id` field in last row of `WriteResult`.

```
db.coll.update(
               { item: "ZZZ135" },
               {  item: "ZZZ135",  stock: 5,  tags: [ "database" ] },
               {upsert: true} 
              )

WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 1,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("54455f33b247e073d7161b32")
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mongo C driver you can use the `bson_t *reply` to receive the returned `_id` in [this function](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/mongoc_collection_command_simple.html):

```
bool mongoc_collection_command_simple (
      mongoc_collection_t       *collection,
      const bson_t              *command,
      const mongoc_read_prefs_t *read_prefs,
      bson_t                    *reply,
      bson_error_t              *error
)
```

The equivalent in C++ is `BSONObj *info` in [this function](http://api.mongodb.org/cxx/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_with_commands.html#afbc1c985c253386696f222ed103ea25f):

```
bool mongo::DBClientWithCommands::simpleCommand (
        const std::string &     dbname,
        BSONObj *   info,
        const std::string &     command 
)
```